# "Resultant" of three polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

The resultant $\operatorname{Res}(f,g)$ of two polynomials over a field $k$ is a polynomial in the coefficients of $f$ and $g$ which enjoys the property of being nonzero if and only if $f$ and $g$ have no common root in an algebraic closure $\overline{k}$ of $k$.

Does there exist a similar construction for three polynomials? There seems to be none. I would like to suggest the following conjecture:

**Conjecture**: there does not exist a function $\operatorname{Res}(f,g,h)$ of three polynomials $f,g,h \in k[x]$, which is a polynomial in the coefficients of $f,g,h$, having the property of being zero if and only if the polynomials $f,g,h$ have a common root in an algebraic closure $\overline{k}$ of $k$.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This can be done using resolvants - which date back to Kronecker if not earlier. Below is an elementary introduction from p.14 of Elkadi et al. [Algebraic geometry and geometric modeling.](http://books.google.com/books?id=6t0Ue_NqJQAC&pg=PA14)
[image]
[image]

Comment: That's great! Kronecker answers my question from the grave.

Answer (score 6):

There is a resultant for three polynomials in two variables. It's considerably trickier than the resultant for two polynomials in one variable.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a bit?
I'm really talking about one variable though. :)

Comment: @Bruno Google "Dixon resultant".